# Determining decreasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

For a sequence $x_{n+1}=4x_n-x_{n-1}$, $x_1=4, x_2=15$, show that the sequence $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ is decreasing

I know from calculating that $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}-\frac{x_{n}}{x_{n-1}}=\frac{-1}{x_nx_{n-1}}$, but I can't seem to prove that.

Any tips please?

Comment: You can't prove that it is decreasing or what?

Answer (score 2):

$$x_{n+1}=4x_n-x_{n-1}$$

divide $x_n$ through out

$\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=4-\dfrac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}$

$\implies \dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} - \dfrac{x_{n}}{x_{n-1}} =4-\dfrac{x_{n-1}}{x_n} - \dfrac{x_{n}}{x_{n-1}} = 4-\dfrac{x_n^2+{x_{n-1}}^2}{x_nx_{n-1}} \le 0$

Because $a^2+b^2\ge 4ab$

Comment: Hey @A. Bruno it doesn't work. I see a big mistake in my answer. Sorry.. please undo the best answer. I'm going to delete and try again

Comment: The mistake in my answer was $a^2+b^2\ge 4ab$. It is false. The correct AM-GM inequality is $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$. I don't yet know how to fix my answer

Answer (score 2):

Sketch:
0. Set $y_n=\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}$ for $n>1$.
1. Prove that $x_n>0$, therefore $y_n>0$
2. Determine the sign of first difference $y_3-y_2$ (it is negative for 
the actual parameters ($x_1,x_2=4,15$).
 
3. Consider the difference of $y_n$:
$
y_{n+1}-y_{n}=(4-\frac{1}{y_n})-(4-\frac{1}{y_{n-1}})=\frac{y_{n}-y_{n-1}}{y_{n}y_{n-1}}
$

It shows us, that the sign of the difference does not change ($y_n>0$).